# Echoing the pts number of the terminal you are running on?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I used a slow approach, namely, executing

```
$ ps | grep bash | grep -oP '/[0-9]+' | grep -oP '[0-9]+'
```

What's a better way of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: The **`tty`** command is the usual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could simply issue:

`tty`

Example:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

And if you **only** want the number of the terminal, do this:

```
$ tty | grep -Po '\d+$'
0
```

From `man tty`:

```
NAME
       tty  -  print  the file name of the terminal connected to
       standard input
```

Comment: Showing a lot of faith that it will never be run on `/dev/tty1` or `/dev/pts/10`...

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I figured whatever error handling is best implemented by OP.

Answer (score 1):

This solution has the advantage that it outputs the empty string and returns failure if the TTY isn't of the format `/dev/pts/###`:

```
tty | grep -Po '(?<=^/dev/pts/)\d+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -o tty= -p "$$"
```

Gives you the *controlling tty* (in an unspecified format, though in the implementations I know, that's the path of the device without the `/dev/` prefix)  of the process whose pid is in `$$`, which is the process that executed the shell. `ps` itself will be a child of that process or of a child of that process and will be in the same session so have the same controlling tty.

That would be the same tty `/dev/tty` points to.

If the session has no controlling tty (typically, if it the shell was not started in a terminal, but by some daemon like `cron` and running in the shadows), you'll get `?`. If the process that executed the shell has died, you'll get no output.

The `tty` command prints a path of the tty device open on stdin if any and something like a *not a tty* error if not.

So:

```
controlling_tty=$(ps -o tty= -p "$$")
case $controlling_tty in
  ('?') echo>&2 'No controlling tty'; exit 1;;
  ('') echo>&2 'Cannot determine the controlling tty'; exit 1;;
  (*) controlling_tty=/dev/$controlling_tty;;
esac
printf '%s\n' "The controlling tty is $controlling_tty"
```

Or

```
if ! tty_on_stdin=$(tty); then
  echo>&2 'No tty on stdin or cannot determine which it is'
  exit 1
fi
printf '%s\n' "The tty on stdin is $tty_on_stdin"
```

In most real life cases, `$controlling_terminal` and `$tty_on_stdin` will be the same though they don't have to be.

Depending on your use case, you may prefer one of the other. For instance, you'd use `tty` to find out which terminal the input comes from. `ps` to find out on which terminal pressing `^C` would send a SIGINT, `tty<&1` to find out the terminal the output goes to, `tty<&2` for errors.

You could use:

```
tty=$(tty) || { tty=$(tty<&3); } 3<&1 || tty=$(tty<&2)
```

To look for a tty on either of stdin, stdout or stderr and store the first found in `$tty`.

That's what zsh's `$TTY` special variable contains, except that if none of the three file descriptors go to a tty, you get `/dev/tty` if there's a controlling terminal, and the empty string otherwise (instead of `not a tty`).

In any case, that may or may not be a *pseudo* terminal device. The shape of the paths of pseudo-terminal devices varies with the system and version thereof, that may be `/dev/pts/somenumber` or `/dev/ptyx`, etc.